# Removing parenthesis in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to remove parentheses from a string value in this case this one:

(40.703707008, -73.943257966)

I can't seem to find a post with code that works; I know that this is a very simple task, but I've seen the following links but they either kill all my punctuation or don't seem to work. Below is the codes I've tried. Appreciate the help:

[remove parenthesis from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449466/remove-parenthesis-from-string)

[Remove parentheses and text within from strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24173194/remove-parentheses-and-text-within-from-strings-in-r)

```
x = ("(40.703707008, -73.943257966)")
gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",x)
gsub("\\D", "", x)
gsub("log\\(", "", x)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are metacharacters that either needs to be escaped (with `\\`) or we can place it in a square bracket to read it as character.

```
gsub("[()]", "", x)
#[1] "40.703707008, -73.943257966"
```

Comment: Great solution. In case helpful to anyone else, in the case of square brackets you could do something along these lines: `gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x)`